# When Blender model is exported, it looks completely different

Tags: modeling, mesh

When exporting this coin into Roblox Studio, all of its faces seem to be crazy. (No, its not the lighting). Is there a way to fix this?

[image: image in studio]

[image: image in blender]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inverted normals problem. Go into edit mode, select all, and Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside, and I hope that’ll fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much @ZargulTheWizard !! This fixed my problem perfectly